# jQuery: Find all the visible required fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to find all the fields with `required` attribute and they should be `visible` too. Because page can have hidden required fields too. Here is what I tried:

```
function validateRequiredFields()
{
    $('input,textarea,select').attr('required',true).filter(':visible:first').each(function(i, requiredField){

        if($(requiredField).val()=='')
        {
            alert($(requiredField).attr('name'));
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: why do you have the first selector if you are trying to find all?

Comment: attr("required", true) is setting a value, not checking it.

Answer (score 96):

If you want to find input, textarea,or select elements that have the attribute `required` and are `visible` use the [has attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/):

```
$('input,textarea,select').filter('[required]:visible')
```

or

```
$(':input[required]:visible')//might be little costlier
```

Comment: Its's too bad that @Himanshu Yadav didn't mark this answer as correct, because it seems to work for me, almost 10 years on.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to do this for razor elements. Here is the query you need.

```
$('input,textarea,select').filter("[data-val-required]")
```