# How to filter inputs fields in a particular div

Tags: jquery, filter

This filters all the input fields in HTML:

```
var required = $('input, textarea, select').filter('[required]:visible')
```

I want to filter in a particular div:

```
<div id="a">
  <input ... required>
</div>
<div id="b">
  <input ... required>
  <input ... required>
</div>
```

Comment: `$('#a').find('input,textarea,select').filter(....)`

Comment: find doesn't work on some IE

Comment: "find doesn't work on some IE" please clarify that statement as it seems difficult to prove without a lot more context here such as version of browsers and the jQuery you are using etc.

Comment: `find doesn't work on some IE` that's not true at all - unless you're going back to IE5 or 6, in which case you have much bigger issues.

Comment: Please update your question to put up proper HTML and whatever other code you need to provide a reproducible example.  As it stands, this is just a copy of the accepted answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18659726/jquery-find-all-the-visible-required-fields with a statement that it does not work.  We need your actual markup and any other code to prove otherwise.

Comment: Be cognizant of "hidden" vs not visible https://stackoverflow.com/q/17425543/125981

Comment: Please edit your question to add clarity.  1.  How you set visible/not visible 2. proper input tags `<input ... required>` is not a proper tag with the `...` in there. 3. Add clarification of "I want to filter in a particular div:" - do you mean just those two, both of those, ability to choose which one, or something else? 4. You have `select` and `textarea` in your selector by none in your example html; are there some of those in the actual markup?.  5. If you have a browser specific issue (IE) please note that specific and the jQuery version being used.

Comment: @Sysix this worked even on IE

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the following selector, which makes use of [`:input`](https://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) (which will also select `<button>`s, you can switch back to `input,textarea,select` and `filter` if that's not desired):

```
$('#a :input:visible[required]');
```

Replace `#a` with whatever div you want to filter on.

If the elements need to be right under the div, you can use `#a > :input:visible[required]` instead.

**Demo**:

```js
var $required = $('#a :input:visible[required]');

// Just to showcase what this selector matches
$required.css('background-color', 'red');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="a">
  <p>A1: <input type="text" required></p>
  <p>A2: <textarea required></textarea></p>
  <p>A3: <select required><option>option1</option></select></p>
  <p>A4 (hidden, won't be matched): <input type="text" style="display:none" required></p>
</div>
<div id="b">
  <p>B1: <input type="text" required></p>
  <p>B2: <input type="text" required></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Switching back as you have it noted will still select the buttons in the original context prior to the filter.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss Not exactly sure what you mean, but yes, you'd have to keep using `.filter()` then, unless you want to repeat `:visible[required]` for each element name (which would be ugly).

Comment: `<input type="button">` and `<input type="text"/>` both are selected as `$(':input')` and `$('input')` but  as you noted `$(':input')`  also includes the `<button>hi</button>`  so either way you would have to filter out something perhaps...`.not('[type="submit"],[type="button"], button')`

Comment: Perhaps also type `reset` but I think you already know all this, mainly posting for others.

Comment: Sure, depends on what he wants to target exactly. Thanks for the comments.

Comment: @SyedMohammedSMJ You're welcome. You should also mark the answer as accepted (the little “✓” on the left) if it solves your issue.

Comment: Please add `$('#a').find('input,textarea,select').filter(` as this form is preferred when a large DOM is in play due to the right to left selector of the sizzle engine - isolate to the context `$('#a')` first, then the selectors within that context.  Notes here re: context https://stackoverflow.com/q/16422478/125981

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss Very interesting post, thanks for sharing! I'm really surprised that jQuery wouldn't optimize the descendant selector though, by simulating a `find` operation (basically, find the parent then its child, instead of all children then filter by their parent). What about `$('input,textarea,select', '#a')` (or `$('input,textarea,select', $('#a'))`), performance wise?

Comment: It is how CSS selectors work, both those give the context with the latter matching the documentation.